# Capitalizing the first name and last name in python

Tags: python

I have to capitalize a given string which is all in lower case letters. For example, if the name is `adam grant` it should be converted to `Adam Grant`. I have written the code as such but it is giving me a traceback error stating an `unsupported operand of +:'Nonetype' and 'str'`.

Here is the code:

```
def solve(s):
    c=str(s)
    if 0<len(c)<1000:
        a=c.title()
        print(a)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
        s = input()
        result = solve(s)
        fptr.write(result + '\n')
        fptr.close()
```

I am getting the error in the line `fptr.write(result + '\n')`

So, what should I change in this code or add lines to execute this?
Thanks.

Comment: Add the whole traceback code

Comment: `solve()` doesn't return anything so `result` is `None`

Comment: `print()` is not `return`.

Comment: Yes you should return some value not to print it..

Comment: 3 questions. 1: Why do you have `c=str(s)`? Converting a string to a string won't make it _stringier_. 2: Why do you limit the string size? 3: How do you think Python will find out, where `'adamgrant'` has to be split so that you get two single words?

Comment: ok sorry so what if the input is adam grant

Answer (score 0):

One liner,

```
print(' '.join(map(str.capitalize,input().split(' '))))
```

For Hackerrank,

```
def solve(s):
    return ' '.join(map(str.capitalize,s.split(' ')))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
    s = input()
    result = solve(s)
    fptr.write(result + '\n')
    fptr.close()
```

Comment: This worked for several test cases but for 1 w 2 r 3g string, it is not working. Could you explain why?

Comment: Please give the string which doesn't pass the test.. in proper way

Comment: @AbburuManish please mention the strings in a code format..

Comment: 1 w 2 r 3g is the string itself. This is only the string the spaces are also there

Comment: what should be the output for that string?

Comment: '1 w 2 r 3g' is the string

Comment: the  output should be 1 W 2 R 3g but I don't understand why is the 3g remained 3g only

Comment: Nope, the initial sample test case is only not passing now!

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the actual problem which is asked in hackerrank..

Comment: To solve this I need to view complete problem statement..

Comment: can we add the photo in chat box?

Comment: Well, I have reached my question limit it seems

Comment: Check my recent answer I hope it will pass all cases..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232896/discussion-between-nanthakumar-j-j-and-abburu-manish).

Answer (score 0):

```
def solve(s):
    c=str(s)
    if 0<len(c)<1000:
        a=c.title()
        print(a)
        return a
    else:
       # otherwise None will be returned 
       # and None can't be '+' to '\n'
       # when fptr.write(result + '\n')
       return c # replace it or handle it yourself


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
    s = input()
    result = solve(s)
    fptr.write(result + '\n')
    fptr.close()
```

Comment: This worked for several test cases but for 1 w 2 r 3g string, it is not working. Could you explain why?

Comment: Can you write those test cases?

Comment: 1 w 2 r 3g  this one test case

Comment: What is your expected output for this test case?

Comment: 1 W 2 R 3g is the output

Comment: No I think it is working correctly.  check here https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OSwdsMD4nyiKRPeSTJEd24RmVBxGM0eK?usp=sharing

Comment: It outputs "1 W 2 R 3G".  Check it let me know

Answer (score 0):

The answers above do not explain your mistake. Your function does not contain any `return` statements, meaning that when you assign `result` to the function it just gets assigned `None`. To fix this, `return` instead of `print`.

Answer (score 0):

The line `result = solve(s)` is expecting a returned value from the function `solve(s)`. So you should return the results in the final line of the function.

```
def solve(s):
    output = ' '.join(map(lambda x: x.title() if x.isalpha() else x, s.split()))
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
    s = input()
    result = solve(s)
    fptr.write(result + '\n')
    fptr.close()
```

For example, if input is `1 w 2 r 3g`, the output `1 W 2 R 3g`

Alternatively,

```
def solve(s):
    for x in s.split():
        s = s.replace(x, x.capitalize())
    return s
```

Comment: This worked for several test cases but for 1 w 2 r 3g string, it is not working. Could you explain why?

Comment: how about `def solve(s): return str(s).title()` ?

Comment: nope same error not passing for the one test case

Comment: do you have the input example for the test case?

Comment: ok i've updated my code, please take a look

Comment: result=solve() is a template code given by them we cannot change it so I couldn't

Comment: hi @AbburuManish, have you tried my answer?

Comment: if you need help in other hackerrank questions, I have compiled here https://github.com/JNYH/HackerRank_solutions